# Environment variables in Envoy config

Tags: envoyproxy

How could i use environment variable in the envoy-config.xml . I am deploying envoy using the docker image.
for example in below case i want to change the port number (EDGE_ENVOY_ADMIN_PORT) which is defined in my .env file

```
admin:
  access_log_path: "/opt/edge-envoy/logs/admin_access.log"
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: "0.0.0.0"
      port_value:   ${EDGE_ENVOY_ADMIN_PORT}
```

is there any way such token replacement functionality available in envoy?

Answer (score 1):

No, envoy won't do the token replacement as its reading in the config file.  You could perhaps overload the `RUN` command to do a `sed` replacement from your env var before the normal envoy run command.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to prepare an envoy configuration template with specific keywords instead of values and replace the keywords with real values which is being read from env-vars while deployment. You can not do env injection inside the envoy configuration.